# /root partition is filled up

Tags: storage, root-filesystem, endeavouros

Recently, my EndeavourOS install has been sending me a notification saying that my root filesystem was filled up, with 0 MiB remaining. What could be done to clean up the root system?

Output of `sudo du -h --max-depth=1`:

```
9,8G    ./usr
125M    ./boot
50M ./root
0   ./dev
du: cannot access './proc/3667/task/3667/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3667/task/3667/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3667/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3667/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   ./proc
16K ./lost+found
24K ./tmp
229G    ./home
0   ./sys
293M    ./opt
27M ./etc
8,0G    ./var
12G ./run
12K ./srv
4,0K    ./mnt
259G    .
```

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             7,6G     0  7,6G   0% /dev
run             7,6G  1,7M  7,6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2   20G   19G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7,6G   71M  7,5G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7,6G  1,5M  7,6G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p4  500M  324K  499M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p3  259G  229G   17G  94% /home
tmpfs           1,6G   92K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p1   15G   12G  3,4G  78% /run/media/dion/_________
/dev/nvme0n1p1   17G   24K   16G   1% /run/media/dion/71f8f1fe-5a7d-433f-aa03-84b679c7e2d9
```

Comment: Your `df -h --max-depth=1` output is from your home directory (which is 94% full), but the root filesystem is under `/` (100%), so you'll need to check what fills up that directory and remove unused files.

Comment: So `/usr` and `/var` are filling up the root filesystem (by the way, it's always a good idea to use LVM and use separate LVs for these directories). You should also check `/var/log`  for many and/or large files and clean them up. If you get back some free space you can check if there are unused programs you could remove, that would free up some space in `/usr` and probably a little bit in `/var`. too.

Comment: Run `du /var | sort -n` and tell us what the largest directories are. They're probably filled with either log files, which can be trimmed, or data files, which may need to be moved to a different filesystem.

Comment: Try `du -kx /  | sort -rn | less` to see the directories on the root filesystem sorted by size. When using `du` to find large things in the root filesystem, you'll almost always want to use the `-x` option to avoid mixing other filesystems (both on-disk ones like your `/home` and virtual RAM-based ones like `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys` and `/run`) in the size calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your root partition is really filled up (19 GiB out of 20 GiB, less than 1 GiB left). If you want to keep your partition as is, you need to remove some packages or otherwise free up some spaces (rotate logs, clear pacman cache, delete foreign locale and such). But probably you'll still hit this again soon.

Best thing you can do is to expand your root. Boot in a live usb and Gparted/ Kde Partition manager would do the job. Alternately, you can use cli programms too, from a live USB.